# Why are anonymous functions used in ioc containers like Pimple

Tags: php, oop, inversion-of-control

I know in Pimple container, dependencies are declared as

```
$container = new Pimple(); 
$container['db'] = function (){
  return new SomeClass; 
};
```

My question is what if I just declared dependencies as simple arrays like this.

```
$container = new Pimple();
$container['db'] = new SomeClass;
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is something called [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), specifically [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#Lazy_initialization).

In your first example `SomeClass` is not actually instantiated until it is requested. In your second example it is instantiated right away. So, even if the request never hits the database the object is created and a connection is established.

By using your first example the connection to the database is never established if the request never actually uses the database.

Comment: Now it makes sense, just like a normal function that the resource defined/declared inside it, is never available until the function is  called right?